# How to use "ls -l" to output a specified part?

Tags: bash, shell

`ls -l /` Output:

```
lrwxrwxrwx.   1 root root     7 Feb  4  2016 bin -> usr/bin
...
```

But sometimes I want this:

```
lrwxrwxrwx. bin -> usr/bin
...
```

or this:

```
Feb  4  2016 bin -> usr/bin
...
```

I know find command can output a specified part with -printf option. How about ls?

Comment: We shouldn't use `ls -l` output for any kind of processing.  `stat` is the best option here, as @williampursell has shown.

Comment: I agree with codeforester. Parsing `ls` is a terrible idea, and [here are some reasons why](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs). Instead, consider using a `for` loop to find the files you're interested in. There are better ways to do whatever it is you're trying to achieve.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want `stat`, not ls.  For your first example:

```
stat -c '%A  %N' /bin
```

For the second

```
stat -c '%y %N' /bin
```

Comment: Note that `stat` options and output vary for different operating systems. The OP hasn't mentioned whether he's using Linux (which this answer assumes) or FreeBSD or OSX which do not have a `-c` option.  (For example, `stat -f '%T%Lp  %N -> %Y' file` might be close in BSD or OSX, though the exact format of `-c '%A %N'` I think cannot be replicated.)

Answer (score 1):

something like this

```
ls -l | awk ' {print  $6, $7, $8, $9, $10} '
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use cut:

```
ls -l | cut -f6-10 -d' '
```

This will print the 6th to 10th columns. It distinguishes columns using whitespace delimiter (-d' ')

Or to print a list instead of a range:

```
ls -l | cut -f1,2,10 -d' '
```

Will print columns 1,2 and 10

Answer (score 0):

```
ls -ld /usr/bin
```

The -d flag prevents the content of the directory to be listed.